# Retaining ruler when digitising in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I just switched from QGIS 3.4.4 to 3.8, and now when I am digitising or editing nodes, the ruler/measuring disappears when I go/click to digitise a shape or edit a node.

I would like to keep my measuring points/markers while i'm digitising/editing.

Is this a setting thing or just part of the update?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what ruler/measuring that you are talking about, but it seems you are talking about `Advanced Digitizing Toolbar` because this is the only tool that I can see measuring or values to enter there.

If you are looking for `Advanced Digitizing Toolbar`, it exists in both QGIS 3.4 and 3.8 versions, but maybe not shown clearly. Right-click on the toolbars above the canvas and under Toolbars, select `Advanced Digitizing Toolbar`

[image]

Remember that `Advanced Digitizing Toolbar` will be ONLY if the data that you are working is projected which means a CRS that uses meter or feet units. If you working with geographic data the toolbar will not be activated and you cannot see the measurements.

[image]

Comment: I think they were talking about the Measure tool in the Attributes toolbar (Measure Line, Measure Area or Measure Angle). It can be useful to measure a distance, and then keep the measurement rubberband on the screen as a guide. Your explanation of the advanced digitizing tools might be a helpful workaround though.

Comment: @csk Thank you for your explanation. I think the OP should clarify his point and add additional information of what exactly he wants.